# Copying files with a specific extension from multiple directories

Tags: batch-file, xcopy

If I have several directories that contain, lets say, word documents and I want to copy every single file in the parent directory that have the ".doc" extension, how could I do that in a batch file?

I know that if I write:

```
xcopy "C:\Users\Documents\*.doc" C:\Users\NewDestination /s /i
```

I'll copy all .doc files in the Documents directory to a new destination, but what if the only .doc files in Documents are located in subdirectories? How could I do that without having to write an `xcopy` line for each subdirectory?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
for /r "C:\Users\Documents\" %# in (*doc) do @copy %# "C:\Users\NewDestination" /Y
```

or when used from batch file:

```
for /r "C:\Users\Documents\" %%# in (*doc) do copy %%# "C:\Users\NewDestination" /Y
```

Comment: what if I wanted to copy .txt files in addition to .doc files?